# UITableView does not enter editing mode

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I've tried many times to create a table view and delete certain rows, I even asked this question here before and implemented what they advised but yet failed to even get my table

ViewController.h

```
   @interface XYZViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

        @property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *myTable;
        @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *names;
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *editButton;

    - (IBAction)editMyTable:(id)sender;

    @end
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation XYZViewController

@synthesize names, myTable, editButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //input values into the mutable array
    names = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:

             @"Bob",
             @"Chris",
             @"Tom"

              , nil];

    editButton = self.editButtonItem;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return @"Friends";

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.names count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //create an identifier
    static NSString *identifier;

    //create the cell with the identifier
    UITableViewCell *cell = [myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    //check if cell is nil
    if (cell == nil) {

        //assign cell
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];

    }

    //assign the names of the array to each cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}

- (IBAction)editMyTable:(id)sender
{

    [editButton setTitle:@"Done"];
    [myTable setEditing:YES animated:YES];

}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [myTable setEditing:editing animated:animated];

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return YES;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        //remove from array
        [names removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //remove from tableView
        [myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Image: http://postimg.org/image/g9wqwuo6v/

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Is the IBAction wired up to the `edit` button properly? Also remove your overriding of `setEditing:animated:`. In your `IBAction` you are setting the editing property of the table. There is no reason for your VC to override this (it is probably ever even called).

Comment: Yes, my `IBAction` is set up properly. http://postimg.org/image/lduq1kd2p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your issue is that you have not wired up your `myTable` property. It is not an `IBOutlet` and nowhere in your code do you establish the connection. When you call `[myTable setEditing:YES animated:YES];` it is sending it to a `nil` table. You can verify this by printing out `myTable`'s value before calling the edit method: `NSLog(@"%@", myTable);`.

Also you should remove your overriding of `setEditing:animated:` since you are a `UIViewController` subclass and not a `UITableView` subclass. Just making your initial call in your `IBAction` should be enough.

Comment: You are right, I am not getting anything when I log it. However, I did connect `myTable` property: http://postimg.org/image/cdv33a8ix/

Comment: You just connected its `delegate` and `datasource`. That is just used for it to ask questions. You do not connected it to the `myTable` property though... Make `myTable` an `IBOutlet` (like `editButton`) and connect the table to that property. Then accesses it using `self.myTable`.